# How to parse record set using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I am using ColdFusion 9.0.1 and jQuery 1.6.2.

I am doing an call using CFAJAXPROXY and jQuery like this:

```
var jro = new jsApp();
MyResults = jro.getProductPricing(CustomerID, OrderID, ProductID);
```

I will always get one result back.  Here is a sample of the result I get back:

```
{"COLUMNS":["PRICE","POINTS","BV","DESCRIPTION"],"DATA":[[14.990000,6.8,6.00,"CLEAR VANILLA 11OZ-325ML"]]}
```

When I get this result back, I need to parse it and populate spans within the page.

I have never tried to parse JSON like this.  This seems like it should be very simple to parse, but every example I see makes it look like rocket science.  How to I use jQuery to get at the PRICE, POINTS, BV, and DESCRIPTION columns?  Is there a bad way to do this?  What's a good way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [`setQueryFormat('column')`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-79f9.html) that you can call before invoking the webservice so that the resulting JSON object is easier to access or manipulate, but the down side of this is the resulting JSON string will be bigger because the column names are repeated for every record in the recordset.

> If you use the cfajaxproxy tag and call the proxy object’s
>   setQueryFormat function with a parameter value of column ColdFusion
>   client-side binding and proxy code does not convert column format data
>   into JavaScript that is consumed directly by HTML grids. However, use
>   this format with the cfajaxproxy tag, because you can refer to the
>   returned data by using the column names directly. For example, if a
>   CFC function returns a query with user data, you get the user names in
>   your JavaScript by specifying values such as `userData.firstName[0]` and
>   `userData.lastName[0]`.

CF Dev Doc: Using data interchange formats
-> [Controlling CFC remote return value data format](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-626a.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec10e40-7ff6)

Comment: I couldn't get this to work for me in the manner you described. I did have some luck with it though.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a well formed `JSON` object and can be accessed easily. If it is in the form a string then you can use `$.pareseJSON()` method to parse the string into JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

This code assumes MyResults is a JS object, rather than a JSON string.  If you don't have the JSON deserialized into a JS object yet, then do as ShankarSangoli suggests and run it through parseJSON first: MyResults = $.parseJSON(MyResults);

```
queryIndex = new Object();
for (var i = 0; i < MyResults["COLUMNS"].length; i++)
{
    queryIndex[MyResults["COLUMNS"][i]] = i;
}

for (i = 0; i < MyResults["DATA"].length; i++)
{
    $('span#foo').text('Price: '+ MyResults["DATA"][i][queryIndex["PRICE"]]);
    $('span#bar').text('POINTS: '+ MyResults["DATA"][i][queryIndex["POINTS"]]);
    // etc....

}
```

Comment: This is based on some code that I've used quite a bit.  I have to say, though, that I find it easier to work with jQuery's $.getJSON function than any of the cfajaxproxy stuff.  To each his own, though.